# Select last N rows from MySQL - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using `codeigniter`;

I would like to get last `N` rows from my table.

In my query I want to get last 200 rows:

```
         $this->m_general->select('count(*)');
         $this->m_general->from('pm');
         $result_count_query = $this->m_general->get();
         $count_query = $result_count_query->num_rows();



$data['all']     = $this->m_general->get('pm', array( 'admin_delete'=>0 ) , $count_query-200,$count_query, array('admin_seen'=>'asc' , 'id'=>'desc') );
```

but it returns nothing.

where is my wrong ?

**updated**

below query not worked fine and it returns all records :

```
$data['all']     = $this->m_general->get('pm', array( 'admin_delete'=>0 ) ,200, array('admin_seen'=>'asc' , 'id'=>'desc') );
```

Comment: Why not just changing your order by direction, and do top 200 instead without offset.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: What's the api of the get method. You have a different number of parameters in your examples.

Comment: ohhh, updated my query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Solve the Problem

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE admin_delete= 0 AND admin_seen=0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT  200");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);

if(empty($count))
{
    echo 'array is empty';
}
else{
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the API

> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Looks like you can't do this with the `get` method. 
Build your query according to the API.

```
$this->m_general->limit(200);
$this->m_general->order_by("admin_seen", "asc");
$this->m_general->order_by("id", "desc"); 

$data['all']     = 
$this->m_general->get('pm', array( 'admin_delete'=>0 ));
```